# Why does local inference differ from the API when computing Jina embeddings?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers, jina

I am computing [Jina v2 embeddings](https://jina.ai/news/jina-embeddings-2-the-best-solution-for-embedding-long-documents/) via the `transformers` Python libraries and via the API (see https://jina.ai/embeddings/).

With `transformers` I can run something like

```py
from transformers import AutoModel

sentences = ['How is the weather today?']

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-en', trust_remote_code=True)
embeddings_1 = model.encode(sentences)
```

or

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model = SentenceTransformer('jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-en')
embeddings_2 = model.encode(sentences)
```

and the resulting `embeddings_1` and `embeddings_2` match.

However if I use the Jina API e.g. via

```py
import requests

url = 'https://api.jina.ai/v1/embeddings'

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer jina_123456...' # visit https://jina.ai/embeddings/ for an API key
}

data = {
  'input': sentences,
  'model': 'jina-embeddings-v2-base-en' # note that the model name matches
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
embeddings_3 = eval(response.content)["data"][0]["embedding"]
```

`embeddings_3` differ from the other two arrays by a small difference, around 2e-4 in absolute value on average. I see this discrepancy both with CPU and GPU runtimes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://huggingface.co/jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-en/discussions/38 for enhanced visibility

Answer (score 1):

The API side usually applies some optimization (e.g., half-precision fp16) for higher performance. You can try the following example:

```py
from transformers import AutoModel
import torch
sentences = ['How is the weather today?']
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('jinaai/jina-embeddings-v2-base-en', trust_remote_code=True, attn_implementation='torch', torch_dtype=torch.float16, device_map='cuda')
embeddings_1 = model.encode(sentences)
```

Comment: Thanks! Even with `torch.float16` I get embeddings that differ from those I get via https://jina.ai/embeddings/. This was a very plausible explanation, but I am not 100% sure that this is correct.